# Multiple SQL WHERE query in node.JS using Array

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I need simply code in my SQL query. Using SET is possible to do with an  Array, but when i do with WHERE query, there's any error. Is it possible using WHERE in arary? 
I've been read documentation but i can't found it for MULTIPLES WHERE query

Example :

```js
var values = {
  date : "2017-03-03 12:11:09",
  ticket_id : "12212",
  status : "Done"
}

var condition = {
  id : 21,
  status : "Pending"
}

pool.query("UPDATE queue SET ? WHERE ??", [values, condition], function(err, results){
   if(err){
      console.log(err)
      return
    }
    console.log(results)
})
```

And i found some error

```
{ Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `status` = 'Pending'' at line 1
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't have an array of conditions. You would have to build it up manually and be careful of the possibility of SQL injection.

You could use another query interface to achieve what you wanted. For example, I came across:

- [Waterline docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs)
- [node-sql-query](https://github.com/dresende/node-sql-query)

Both of these appear to build queries. You will have to do further research to see if either of these or another similar package will do what you want.